# Calculated Field with Multiple Columns

Tags: calculated-column

Thanks for providing this website as a resource.  I am needing some help with coding a Calculated Field.
I have 4 columns that all have an answer of Displayed or Not Displayed.  In my calculated field, I'd like for it to give me a "pass" or "fail" depending on the criteria set below:

If one of the columns includes a "Not Displayed", the observation would be marked as fail.

I'm able to do this in excel but can't get the formula to work in Sharepoint. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you try this formula: `=IF(AND(A1="Displayed", B1="Displayed", C1="Displayed"), "Pass", "Fail")`

Comment: Thank you.  After i posted this request for help, i figured it out.  I did exactly what you suggested.

Comment: Great, than please post the answer below and tick mark it to close the question :)